# Create tablegroup with 4 different values ordered by other value by select in mariadb

Tags: mysql, sorting, select, group

from a table i want to create groups by 4 different "Klasse" ordered by KW in one select query.

| id | Name | Klasse | Resonanz | KW | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | VolkerKnecht | Kreuzritter | 570 | 13777 | 8888 |
| 9 | Aergernis | Zauberer | 710 | 12075 | 13444 |
| 14 | Utherus | Dämonenjäger | 770 | 11100 | 8888 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 15 | Belzepoop | Mönch | 670 | 10101 |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 3 | Loddar | Barbar | 470 | 9876 | 8888 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 5 | WootanFall | Totenbeschwörer | 810 | 8956 | 8888 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Each group of 4 **must NOT contain** same "Klasse" and the next group have to be the next highest KW.

output wanted:

| Groupname | Players |
| --- | --- |
| grp1 | VolkerKnecht,Aergernis,Utherus,Belzepoop |
| grp2 | SiliconWilly,Siegesmund,Eisenklaus,Loddar |
| ... | ... |

so grp1 contains "Klasse" = 1 "Kreuzritter", 1 "Zauberer", 1 "Dämonenjäger", 1 "Mönch" with the highest KW

grp2: contains "Klasse" = 1 "Dämonenjäger", 1 "Zauberer", 1 "Kreuzritter", 1 "Barbar" (2nd best KW constalation)

grpX can have any other constalation by "Klasse" but the next highest KW group

**fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc2f87/1/0**

it may happen that i further need some more WHEREs and excludes "Klasse" to make this table come to my wishes

Thank you very kindly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem could not be solved by SQL and should be implemented it in back-end code. Here is the closed query that could group your data into group of 4 `Klasse`.

```
-- 3. start part 3
SELECT CONCAT('group', FLOOR(row_number/4) + 1) AS Groupname, GROUP_CONCAT(Name) AS Players
FROM
  -- 2. start part 2
  (SELECT part1.*, (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS row_number
  FROM
    -- 1. start part 1
    (SELECT 
         Klasse, Name, KW,
         (@class_rank := CASE WHEN @klasse = Klasse THEN @class_rank + 1 ELSE 0 END) AS class_rank,
         @klasse := Klasse
     FROM valar_date
         CROSS JOIN (SELECT @class_rank := -1, @klasse := '') param1
     ORDER BY Klasse, KW+0 DESC) part1
     -- 1. end part 1
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := -1) param2
  ORDER BY part1.class_rank, part1.KW DESC) part2
  -- 2. end part 2
GROUP BY FLOOR(row_number/4);
-- 3. end part 3
```

Explanation of the above query:

1. Part 1: ranking data inside each `Klasse` by value of `KW` column.
2. Part 2: ordering data by ranking value of step 1, then assign row number for each record. By doing this, data will be ordered from the highest ranking to the lowest ranking of each group.
3. Part 3: grouping each 4 records into 1 group.

See demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc2f87/37)

Comment: not exactly what i am looking for, i want to have 4 different "Klasse" in each group - but thank you so far - so i like to have the best 4 by KW with different "Klasse" players in a group -

Comment: I think I phrased the question wrong - now edited

Comment: @Shorty  Which MySQL version are you using, is it MySQL 5.6?

Comment: mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.48-MariaDB, for xxx-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2 --- mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev   - are there restrictions?

Comment: I think your requirement could not be solved by using SQL. Anyway, I've tried to find the solution and edited answer for your reference,  please check. Hope it would help you.

Comment: Wow - thank you very much for your great effort! i have to check this manually - but it looks very precisely close to my wishes. anyway - this helped me a lot!